# No quotes around String in CSV File For Import

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import a 3.3Gb .csv file over a network connection into an Amazon RDS Database running an innoDB engine.  It usually runs for 1.5 to 3 hours, but doesn't import the file and returns a 2013 network connection failure problem.

```
   truncate Option_Data;
    set autocommit = 0;
    set unique_checks = 0;
    set foreign_key_checks =0;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Chris/Downloads/EOD_20161210.csv'   INTO TABLE Stock_Data;
    commit;
```

The first field of the table is a character field, but the data does not have the necessary quotes ('') to designate a string.  So, all of the data is being imported into the first field and causing issues with the import, not to mention the problem with the data being in the incorrect locations.  Is there a way to get around adding quotes to all of the rows?

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?

Comment: Yes, what might be overlooking that would be causing this issue?

Comment: What happens when you load a *smaller* .csv file. Say, the first 10 lines. e.g. `head -10  /Users/Chris/Downloads/EOD_20161210.csv > /tmp/test.csv`, then do the LOAD DATA with `'/tmp/test.csv'`  ?

Comment: It does, close to what it is supposed to, but it seems I do have an issue with the character type.  The first column is a character, the remaining are real numbers.  However, the first column is not encapsulated with ' '.  So, it seems to be reading all of the commas as text rather than delimiting by them.  The entire row is being imported into the first column.  Would this cause that kind of issue with the run time?